# Navigation in Flutter App - does not work as intended

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I try to build a flutter app and want to navigate trough the pages.
I build a drawer with a menu with several items to open new pages - that works fine.

```
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new Page1(),
          ),
        );
      },
```

By pressing on the Page1 menuitem page1 opens fine.
Inside page1 I have a slidable list with "edit" and "details". I open this with

```
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new DetailsPage(),
          ),
        );
      },
```

In the details Page I see all the things i wanna see, but when I press the Back button in the appBar i am back at home screen with closed drawer.

I tried to put  `onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context);` inside the appBar section but this doesn´t work either.

Now I got what I want by using always `Navigator.push` but I am sure that this is not right, so that navigator stack gets bigger and bigger.

What I do wrong? Why .pop does not bring me to the last page?
Any ideas?

Thx in advance
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line with the `Navigator.of(context).pop();`in the Page1 onTap.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pushReplacement` in any cases you need to remove current page from stack and route to new page.

> Replace the current route of the navigator that most tightly encloses
> the given context by pushing the given route and then disposing the
> previous route once the new route has finished animating in.

[here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html) is the documentation